# How can I write the weibull probability formula?

Tags: equations, subequations, distributions, statistics

I would be very grateful if you could help me on how to write this formula.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is a pretty standard formula that any good introduction to LaTeX should explain how to make:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x; \lambda,k) =
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{k}{\lambda}
    \bigl(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigr)^{k-1}
    e^{(-x/\lambda)^k} & x\geq 0,
    \\
    0 & x< 0,
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `e^{(-x/\lambda)^k}` instead of `e^{-x/\lambda}` :-), anyway +1

Comment: @Zarko fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use cases

```
\[f(x;\lambda,k)=
     \begin{cases} 
          \frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-(x/\lambda)^k} &x\ge 0\\ 0 & x<0
     \end{cases}
\]
```

Answer (score 0):

I heve some variants for You (all of them are very close, but you can choose what you need):

**I**

```
$f(x ; \lambda, k)= \begin{cases}\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x} 
{\lambda}\right)^{k-1} e^{-(x / \lambda)^{k}} & x \geq 0 \\ 0 & 
x<0\end{cases}$
```

**II**

```
\[
f(x ; \lambda, k)= \begin{cases}\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x} 
{\lambda}\right)^{k-1} e^{-(x / \lambda)^{k}} & x \geq 0 \\ 0 & 
x<0\end{cases}
\]
```

**III**

```
\begin{equation}
f(x ; \lambda, k)= \begin{cases}\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x} 
{\lambda}\right)^{k-1} e^{-(x / \lambda)^{k}} & x \geq 0 \\ 0 & 
x<0\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```